# How to catch auto layout constraint redundancies

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In my endeavour to ensure the display of my app will look correct in all size I am struggling obviously with auto layout constraints.

In one of my ViewContoller there a UIView (ContainerView) that resizes programatically to keep the proportion settings regardless of the screen size.

With the ContainerView there is a StackView with 3 UIViews filled equally with spacing.

All those views have been added to the Storyboard.

StackView constraints are on CenterX, CenterY and aspect ratio
UIViews constraints within the StackView are on aspect ratio only

When at ViewDidLoad the ContainerView is resized, it triggers the re-calculation of the StackView in order to again keep the right proportions.

I have managed to make it look right, but when I trigger the code to resize and position the StackView, I get the following messages in the print window that I can't decipher it or at least I don't know how to proceed to correct it.

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to
>   simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>   Probably at least one of the
>   constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
>   Try this: 
>         (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't
>   expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it.  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fe3f9005e20 )>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "= UIView:0x7fe3f9006b70.bottom   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-11-21
>   15:36:38.382957+0100 RTS Game Companion[16230:4711284]
>   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fe3f9005e20 )>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "= UIView:0x7fe3f9006ed0.bottom   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-11-21
>   15:36:38.427959+0100 RTS Game Companion[16230:4711284]
>   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

The code that I use to resize/reposition the StackView is an extension that:

- compares the Width/Height ratio of the ContainerView and the
  StackView
- depending on the result, it either makes the StackView the same
  Height of the Container View or it defines the largest possible Width
  within the Container View that satisfies the aspect ratio constraints
  of the StackView
- reapplies Top, Bottom, Leading and Trailing constraints to the
  StackView to ensure it is centered in the Container View

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of your code? That would make it easier to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a way around this issue.

In fact - and that is what the compiler was telling me, there were auto layout constraints competing with each other.
I had set constraints in a given layout composition and later tried to add more constraints since auto layout would not give me the result I was expecting for each device, but the compiler was telling me that not all constraints could be met since some were just different for the same anchor.

I removed all constraints and test them one by one till I found the right set of constraints.

It may sound trivial, but that was simply about it.